# use of (space) to take input of string

Tags: c, string, input

I am using a Windows 10 machine and codeblocks as IDE. In a code, I saw using whitespace character **(space)** for taking input of a string like

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", s);
```

what is the reason behind it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int t, i, j, temp, len;
    char s[1002];

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--){
        scanf(" %[^\n]", s);
        len = strlen(s);
        for(i = 0, j = (len-1); i < (len/2); i++, j--){
            temp = s[i];
            s[i] = s[j];
            s[j] = temp;
        }

        printf("%s\n", s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this program, the programmer just tried to replace the components of the string

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]", s);` is the syntax for reading a whole line (i.e. until user pressed ENTER). I'll strongly recommend that you use `fgets` instead

Comment: @4386427 There's a big semantic difference between that `scanf` call and `fgets`: `fgets` doesn't skip leading space (which this specific `scanf` format does) and `fgets`leves the ending newline in the buffer (which this `scanf` format doesn't).

Comment: If the previous line was read with scanf and left a newline in the buffer, this will consume it before reading the next whole line. It will not accept empty lines, however.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  You meant the other way 'round.  fgets reads the newline, but the format reads up to the newline and leaves it in the buffer.

Comment: The preceding <space> in `scanf(" %[^\n]", s);` is used just to skip any whitespace character that was previously in the buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space in the beginning of `" %[^\n]"`  matches any number of white space characters ' ', '\t', '\n', etc. in the input, and skips them

Note that for `scanf` specifically, most format specifiers skip white space by design, so do not need the leading space, but three don't:

```
`%n`   — count of characters processed
`%[…]` — scan set
`%c`   — read char.
```

The second part of your expression, is a *scan set*, and is relevant to this discussion in that as written can invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if input to the `scanf()` call is too long.
`%[^\n]` matches all characters except the `newline` (`\n`), so stores it along with the terminating `\0` into `s`.  If input happens to be longer than `s` (in this case > 1001) there will be no room for the terminating `'\0'`, thus resulting in a `char` array without a null termination.  This by itself is not undefined behavior, but calling `len = strlen(s);` on the next line will be.

So, given the maximum input length `char s[1002];` can hold is `1001` (leaving room for `'\0'`) then, a safer expression would be:

```
scanf(" %1001[^\n]", s);
```

which limits input length to the value following `%`, thus leaving room for placement of null terminator.

Comment: @4386427 It seems that the OP is asking about the space inside the format string itself. The leading space before the `%`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - edited to reflect.  Thank you.